# SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

Tags: php, phpmailer

I´m using phpmailer class to send an email.

And when I send the email I get this error: "**SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.**"

I dont have an email server configured on localhost, now I am in doubt if I´m getting this error because of this reason, because I haven´t an email server configured or  if it's because I have something wrong in my code.

Do you know If you do not have a mail server configured this error happens?

Comment: You'l have to specify SMTP configuration if you haven't configured SMTP on your localhost.
Please show us some code, so that we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is exactly what you get, if you use the default host setting of phpmailer, which tries to deliver the mail to localhost. So you probably should set the host property, and depending on this servers configuration properties like user and password.

Comment: Thank you, so I need to configure a email server for my tests in localhost right?

Comment: If you have no other server available, yes.

Comment: I've never done this before, can you tell me in a short way what is needed to configure a email server in localhost? It only do some adjust in the php.ini file in the XAMPP folder?

Comment: That depends heavily on you environment. In ubuntu you can simple use `sudo apt-get install postfix`. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix

Comment: hmm ok, I use windows but I also have ubuntu in other partition..I will change to there now to test...Thanks :)